# How to make menu and footer full screen width?

Tags: html, css, menu, footer

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the menu and footer expand across the screen...as of now they only are body width 960px...

page link: www.kvf.fo/vix

Comment: Use `width: 100%` for menu and footer. If they are wrapped in elements not having the width as 100% use `width: 100vw`.

Comment: Please, remove site on your side, create jsfiddle with problem code and update question with new link.

Comment: This article solved my problem: https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/  - I switched from negative margin to box shadow. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: This article solved my problem: https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/  - I switched from negative margin to box shadow. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your page.
you have wrapped your footer and main content inside body and you have given body *width:960px;*.
so the footer taking 100% width of body i.e 960px.
To get the desired result don't wrap footer inside body.
use different div for footer and main content of the page.
And assign the div *width:960px;* which wrapped main content.
Don't give dody *width:960px;*

Comment: This article solved my problem: https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/  - I switched from negative margin to box shadow. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply set the width to 100% in css, nothing more.

```
#menu {
    width: 100%;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also to get  rid of the spacing on the left: just do:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Which gets rid of all the nasty margins.

Answer (score 0):

body style has a

```
 overflow: hidden
```

You may want to review how you have structured your page